# ASP.net Button Press and Release Event

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Right now I have button click event which is a button down event. 
I was wondering if there was a button detect down and up press in asp.net.

Eg.
Do something when user presses button vs Do something when user releases button

Comment: The idea of a "server-side button release" event would not work in practice. I suggest you familiarize yourself with server-side and client-side events

Comment: There are client-side events that correspond to buttons gaining/losing focus and other mouse events and you *could* connect them up to server-side using Ajax requests, or even a `<form>` submission, but it would not be a good idea.